# why window.focus() not working in Mozilla firefox?

Tags: javascript

I need to focus on window opened on further clicks on anchor tag. I have used the below function to do so.

```
function newwindow(url) 
{ 
    OpenWin = this.open(url,"mywindow");
    OpenWin.focus();
}
```

OpenWin.focus() is not working on Mozilla Firefox. Is there any other solution to focus on window opened on further clicks on anchor tag?

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to allow scripts to raise windows, since Firefox does not allow that by default.

In the `Content` tab of the `Options` dialog, click the `Advanced...` button next to the `Enable Javascript` check box, then check the `Raise and lower windows` box in the resulting dialog.

Comment: I did the change mentioned above. Its still not working in firefox :(

Answer (score 3):

The checkbox does not exist anymore in newer ff versions

The only way to change the setting is the `dom.disable_window_flip` about:config option

Comment: As of 2023, this is still the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable/enable Javascript's `window.focus` event from the Firefox options:

Go to Tools > Options > Content > Advanced > Raise or lower windows

There is no way to overwrite this option serverside, because it was made for exactly that purpose: Hindering windows from stealing focus. Your only option is to use model windows on top of your website, which are essentially "the new popup windows".

Comment: I did the change mentioned above. Its still not working in firefox :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that FF follows the [HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#focus-management) which states the following:

> window . focus()
>
> ```
> Focuses the window. Use of this method is discouraged. Allow the user to control window focus instead.
> ```

i.e. we are not able to do the window focusing.