# How to return focus to the parent window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work as to return the focus to the parent window in Firefox 4 and 5

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
     myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
     myWindow.document.write("<p>The new window.</p>");
     myWindow.blur();
     window.focus();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

</body>
</html>
```

How can I return focus to the parent window using javascript?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085544/why-window-focus-not-working-in-mozilla-firefox

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897430/prevent-window-open-from-focusing/6897462#6897462

Answer (score 20):

You need to give your parent window a name.

Parent.html

```
<a id="link" href="#">Click to child.html </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.name = "parent";
        $('#link').click(function (event){ 
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open("child.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Child.html

```
<a id="link" href="#">Return to Parent </a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#link').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var goBack = window.open('', 'parent');
            goBack.focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, whenever you click the link in child.html, the parent window will be focused.

Comment: Just keeping you honest. That's not JavaScript, that's jQuery. The asker may not be using it.

Comment: The parent window name is stored in `window.opener.name`, so the goBack variable could be rewritten to use it (i.e., `var goBack = window.open('', window.opener.name)`). Here's more info on the [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp) property.

Comment: @Claudix Your comment sounds like this doesn't work ever since, but it is actually working (Chrome 51).

Comment: @renocor Yep, I probably misused the preposition... :P "on" is probably better :P

Comment: Works in chrome 72 even without the focus method.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work if the user focuses on a 3rd tab and comes back to the 2nd one.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for necromancing a very old question, but I ran into the same problem and couldn't find any solution. I eventually solved this by using the following script:

```
e = window;
while (e.frameElement !== null) {e = e.parent;}
e.parent.focus();
```

Apparently, calling just `window.focus();` isn't enough. You have to call the Window's parent's focus method by using `window.parent.focus();` You can't access any other properties from JS from it though, it will give a cross-source error. This script will also work if your script was fired from a frame within a page, assuming the frame and main page share the same source (domain).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can return focus, not without closing the child window:

```
myWindow.close()
```

Comment: I know `window.opener` - it is the equivalent of `window` in the OP (as it is run in the parent window). But I'd thought JS sandboxing wouldn't allow a focus, as it is effectively allowing the JS to control tab/window switching on the client machine.

Comment: I might be lucking out :)  I have no issues with window.opener (up to IE8/FFX3.5) from windows that I explitely open (may be a different store with link href=_blank/_top).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this.

```
const ParentWindowName = 'ParentWindowName';

// here set the parent window name so that you can switch back to it later and open the new window/tab
export const openChildWindow = (id) => {
  window.name = ParentWindowName;
  window.ChildWindowName = window.open('/child', id);
};

// here you can change the focus back to the new window.
export const focusParentWindow = () => {
  window.open('', ParentWindowName).focus();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the above example and it didn't work for me.  I had to use a recursive loop to find the opener until the window didn't have an opener (bad design, I know, but our app has several levels of child windows).  Here is the code example.  I hope it helps:

```
/* This is for the button functionality.  
The button element first comes in.  
This element is then used to get the document that has the element.  
The document window opener is then passed to the focusMain method */
function setFocusOnMain(el){
  var doc = el.ownerDocument;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  focusMain(win.opener.document);
}

/* This is a recursive method that checks for a parent window of the current document.  
If the document has no window opener, focus on this element because this is the Main.  
If the document has a window opener, pass the window opener's document to focusMain. */
function focusMain(doc) {
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  if (win.opener == null) {
    doc.focus();
  } else {
    focusMain(win.opener.document);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

If this is a Window you opened yourself you can use `opener.focus();`