# How existing parent browser tab can be focused while closing the child popup?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to focus the existing parent window tab in the browser while closing the child window popup. But i can able to do for opening new parent window and focus it. Is that possible to open the existing parent window browser tab with focused?.

My code

```
function closepopup() {
        var winRef = window.opener.location;
        var parentwindow = window.open(winRef, '');
        parentwindow.focus();
        window.close();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: "But i can able to do for opening new parent window and focus it." -- I  don't understand this at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return focus to the parent window using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910278/how-to-return-focus-to-the-parent-window-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
window.opener.document.forms(0)." & Your Parent Control Id & ".focus();
window.close();
return false;
```