# Facebook look alike login redirect

Tags: javascript

How can I close the login dialog, focusing again the active browser tab and login ? Just like facebook, google and etc. logins. Can't explain it to myself. Attaching image to explain better what I am trying to do.
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return focus to the parent window using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910278/how-to-return-focus-to-the-parent-window-using-javascript)

Comment: I don't think your question is clear. Are you trying to focus back to the parent window when popup closed or close window programmatically after the login process and get back to the parent?

I believe your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910278/how-to-return-focus-to-the-parent-window-using-javascript