# window.focus() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why window.focus() not working in Mozilla firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085544/why-window-focus-not-working-in-mozilla-firefox)

I am implementing multitab feature for my application and I am finding difficulties to implement those when it comes to set the focus for the opened window. Firefox sets the focus for the first time when the window is opened but next time it doesnt.

For example -

My application always opens in window with name 'baseWindow'. A page has following link -

Link1 - Opens a new window with name 'window2'

onclick for above link has following function

```
    function linkOnClick(){
          var wind1=window.open('window2Page.html','window2');
          wind1.focus();
}
```

When the link is clicked for the first time i.e. window2 doesnt exists, at that time the focus is automatically given to window2.
But if i come on first window and click on the link again then the focus is not given on the window2 it stays on the same window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533335/295852 - I think this might be useful to you

Comment: show more code not just a function

Comment: I don't know about Firefox, but for example Opera allows to suppress pop-ups entirely or let you open them as a new background tab always. You can't get around such user settings with a script. Check if there are similar settings in Firefox.

Comment: i doubt if this can be done.. at least not in a cross-browser fashion..

Comment: yep just use fancybox :)

Comment: @RomanTheGreat i cant use fancybox...i want to do this in javascript :)

Comment: again: put full code, not just a one function

Comment: but that is the only code using which i am opening the window and setting the focus for the opened window

Comment: In `about:config` what do you have `dom.disable_window_flip` set to?

Comment: @robertc sorry i dont know about this config..

Answer (score 1):

Whether `focus()` is allowed to raise existing windows is a user preference in Firefox, defaulting to "no" to deal with all the obnoxious popups/popunders people were creating for a while there....

Answer (score 0):

try this way

> ```
>  function linkOnClick(){
>     return function(){
>      var wind1=window.open('window2Page.html','window2');
>      wind1.focus(); 
>     }
>  }
> ```